# Shortest POSIX command line that eagerly removes dual newline sequences

Tags: code-golf, string

Remove every pair of newline characters, that means every two newline characters appearing together are elided, whereas unaccompanied newline characters remain present.
Example:

```bash
echo -ne 'a\n\nb\nc\n\n\n\nd\n\n\n' | your-command
```

should output the same as

```bash
echo -ne 'ab\ncd\n'
```

Watch out, some POSIX tools have implementations that diverge from the standard.
Please consult https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html before submitting your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Sed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), 22

```bash
sed ':l;s/\n\n//;N;bl'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifmpyRr6Cbl6qgnhiTF5OXFJOXDKJBMAVCqSvUKMT8L05NUVC3yrEu1geJ6etb@1kn5aj//w8A)

Initially I had hoped to do `sed -z 's/\n\n//g'` for a score of 18, but I think `-z` is a GNU extension and not Posix.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work on MacOS. `-z` option is not present either. (This version of sed was written by Diomidis Spinellis for FreeBSD. It's expected to be a superset of the IEEE Std 1003.2 (``POSIX.2'') specification.)

Comment: Figured it out: `sed -E ':l;s/\n\n//;N;bl'` on MacOS. A known bug.

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 32 bytes

```bash
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n";ORS="";} 1'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifmpyRr6Cbl6qgnhiTF5OXFJOXDKJBMAVCqSvUKMT8TyzPVlB3cnX39KsOCrZVAkkoWfuDmErWtQqG6v//AwA)

Comment: I'm not talking about practical use though. I'm saying your answer is invalid, since nothing in the challenge's spec says you can assume there's a character that's not in the input string.

Comment: [See this standard loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1789/6484).

Comment: Your answer is invalid regardless of tags. Most standard loopholes (including this one) aren’t tag-specific.

Comment: @Grimmy Ah, didn't know that - thanks for bring me up to speed. :-)

Comment: @Grimmy Fixed that.

Comment: Hi @Noodle9, unfortunately this is still not a valid POSIX solution, because the `b` command can't be followed by a semicolon according to the spec.
"[Editing commands other than {...}, a, b, c, i, r, t, w, :, and # can be followed by a <semicolon>](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)."

Comment: @ggPeti Fixed that.

Comment: I admire your perseverance.

Answer (score 1):

### AWK, <s>26</s> 22 bytes

```
awk -vRS='

' -vORS= 1
```

Tested with `gawk` and `mawk` on MacOS.

Edit: saved 4 bytes thanks to @AndersKaseorg.

Comment: You can remove the second `""` pair (−2 bytes), and you can replace the `\n\n` with two literal newlines (−2 bytes).